# Displaying images from database in an ASP.NET MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to Asp.NET MVC development and a I want to make an application that displays multiple images from a database in the same View. I'm storing  the images as LONGBLOB and converting then to a base 64 string.

I'm trying to display them like this:

`<img src=<%:Html.Value("photo")%> />`

However, I think that the URL doesn't support too big strings as parameters.

My Question is: Which is the best way to display images from database? I need to store them in a image server? Create a maps route to save the images in each URL?

I hope it was clear.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

- Create a controller action that returns a `FileContentResult`
- Pull the data from the database into either a Stream or a Byte array
- From the action, use one of the [Controller.File Method Overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file%28v=vs.108%29.aspx), passing in your image content and mime type, and return that from the action.
- Set your img src attribute to the URL for the controller action, passing whatever parameters are needed to identify the image you want to return from the database.

Answer (score -1):

```
public ActionResult MYsample()
{
    var MyList = storeDB.GenreList();
    var a= MyList.Count;

    if (a != null)
    {
        foreach (var li in MyList)
        {
            return File(li.fileContent, li.mimeType,li.fileName);
        }
    }
    return View(MyList);
}
```

View

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
        <img src="@Url.Action("MYsample", "HomeController", new { id = item.ProductID })" alt="@item.Productname" />
}
```